# Is it possible to compile Framework in to php extension?

Tags: php, compiler-construction, frameworks

Have any one thought of compiling Zend Framework or any other php framework in to DLL or SO library like PDO for example, is that entirely possible and what side effects can it cause?

Comment: There's PHP compilers, but they can't handle all the possible ways PHP code can execute, so they can't generated a "perfect" so/dll that will work 100% - you'll always need the full PHP interpreter to handle the oddball cases.

Comment: facebook developed a php compiler called hiphop: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way would be to provide your package via PEAR. Alternatively you can pack up your package into an [PHP archive](http://php.net/phar).

There is a PHP compiler from Facebook called [HipHop-PHP](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php), but it does currently not support all functionality (Zend Framework can't be compiled yet). There's also [Roadsend PHP](http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php) which is currently being re-implemented.

There's no way to compile a normal PHP application as an php extension (yet?!).